# Is there any negative performance implication to using local functions in Rust?

Tags: function, memory, rust, runtime

I recently realized that I could create local functions in Rust (a function within a function).  Seems like a good way to clean up my code without polluting the function space of a file.  Small sample of what I mean below by local function vs an 'external' function:

```
fn main() {
    fn local_plus(x: i64, y: i64) -> i64 {
        x + y
    }
    let x = 2i64;
    let y = 5i64;

    let local_res = local_plus(x, y);
    let external_res = external_plus(x,y);
    assert_eq!(local_res, external_res);
}

fn external_plus(x: i64, y: i64)  -> i64 {
    x + y
}
```

I was wondering if there is any negative performance implication of doing this?  Like does Rust re-declare the function or take up some undesired amount of function space each time the containing function runs?  Or does it have literally no performance implication?

As a bit of an aside, any tips on how I could have found out the answer for myself (either through reading any specific set of documents, or tooling I could use) would be welcome.

Comment: You could find it yourself by running some benchmarks or checking the MIR/assembly output as I did.

Comment: @ljedrz: Benchmarks are fickle beasts, best check the unoptimized and optimized MIR/LLVM IR/assembly.

Comment: @MatthieuM. agreed - benchmarks are better suited for more complex cases where the other ways are no longer practical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no impact; I checked the assembly generated for both variants and it is identical.

The two versions I compared:

"external":

```
fn main() {
    let x = 2i64;
    let y = 5i64;

    let external_res = external_plus(x,y);
}

fn external_plus(x: i64, y: i64)  -> i64 {
    x + y
}
```

"local":

```
fn main() {
    fn local_plus(x: i64, y: i64) -> i64 {
        x + y
    }
    let x = 2i64;
    let y = 5i64;

    let local_res = local_plus(x, y);
}
```

And both yield the same asm result (release mode in today's nightly):

```
    .text
    .file   "rust_out.cgu-0.rs"
    .section    .text._ZN8rust_out4main17hb497928495d48c40E,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8rust_out4main17hb497928495d48c40E,@function
_ZN8rust_out4main17hb497928495d48c40E:
    .cfi_startproc
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _ZN8rust_out4main17hb497928495d48c40E, .Lfunc_end0-_ZN8rust_out4main17hb497928495d48c40E
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    .text.main,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:
    .cfi_startproc
    movq    %rsi, %rax
    movq    %rdi, %rcx
    leaq    _ZN8rust_out4main17hb497928495d48c40E(%rip), %rdi
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    jmp _ZN3std2rt10lang_start17h14cbded5fe3cd915E@PLT
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end1-main
    .cfi_endproc


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Which means there will be zero difference (not only performance-wise) in the generated binary.

What is more, it doesn't even matter if you use a function; the following approach:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 2i64;
    let y = 5i64;

    let res = x + y;
}
```

Also yields the same assembly.

The bottom line is that, in general, the functions get inlined regardless of whether you declare them in `main()` or outside it.

**Edit**: as Shepmaster pointed out, in this program there are no side effects, so the generated assembly for both variants is actually the same as the one for:

```
fn main() {}
```

However, the MIR output for both is the same, too (and different than one for a blank `main()`), so there shouldn't be any difference coming from the function location even if side effects were present.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the optimizer is removing everything in the program, as it has no observable side effects. `res` is completely unused, so I think you'd see the same for `fn main() {}`.

Comment: @Shepmaster TIL :). I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

> As a bit of an aside, any tips on how I could have found out the answer for myself (either through reading any specific set of documents, or tooling I could use) would be welcome.

Do you know of [the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)?

Enter your code, click on "LLVM IR", "Assembly" or "MIR" instead of "Run", and you get to see what is the low-level representation emitted for said code.

I personally prefer LLVM IR (I'm used to reading it from C++), which is still quite higher level than assembly whilst still being *post* language.

> I was wondering if there is any negative performance implication of doing this?

That's a very complicated question; actually.

The **only difference** between declaring a function locally or externally in Rust **is one of scope**. Declaring it locally simply reduces its scope. **Nothing else**.

However... scope, and usage, can have drastic effects on compilation.

A function that is used only once, for example, is much more likely to be inlined than a function that is used 10 times. A compiler cannot easily estimate the number of uses of a `pub` function (unbounded), but has perfect knowledge for local or non-`pub` functions. And whether a function is inlined or not can drastically affect the performance profile (for worse or better).

So, by reducing the scope, and thereby limiting the usage, you are encouraging the compiler to consider your function for inlining (unless your mark it "cold").

On the other hand, since the scope is reduced, it cannot be shared (obviously).

> So... what?

Follow the usage: define an item in the tightest scope possible.

This is **encapsulation**: now, the next time you need to modify this piece, you will know exactly the impacted scope.

Have some trust in Rust, it won't be introducing overhead if it can avoid it.

Comment: Great answer! Minor nitpick though: maybe you want to stress that there are no *direct* effects. For example, in Java there are a some kinds of "inner classes" that automatically have a reference to the outer one. The same with Rust closures (simply speaking). So I'd say it's important to make clear that inner functions do not reference anything from their enclosing function and do not take up stack-space of the enclosing function. Only *indirect* effects on inlining.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I added some bold here. I am reluctant to start a list of what it does NOT affect as I fear it could lead people to think that maybe if it's not in the list it's affected, so instead I emphasized (more) that it only affected scope and nothing else.