# Is there any neagative performance implication to using local struct in Rsut?

Tags: rust

Same question as [Is there any negative performance implication to using local functions in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971343/is-there-any-negative-performance-implication-to-using-local-functions-in-rust) but for struct.

```
fn bla() -> PublicStruct {
   MyHiddenStruct {bla:String};
   let m = MyHiddenStruct{bla: "aa".to_string()};
   // some work...
   m.into()
}
```

Edit: Indeed I tried a little benchmark with criterion

```
innerouterstruct/outer struct
                        time:   [901.16 ps 905.16 ps 910.44 ps]
                        
innerouterstruct/inner struct
                        time:   [901.10 ps 903.89 ps 907.31 ps]
```

Comment: Same comment: Do some experiments. ;-) Add your results to the post, and if something is not clear, write a specific question.

Comment: The concept of a struct really only exists at compile time, so I'd say no, there is no impact. But I agree with busybee, if it's that critical, just benchmark it

Answer (score 2):

No. The only thing this affects is the visibility of the struct (and its name). Codegen is not affected at all.